# I Froze My Computer’s Clock With CMD And I Can’t Unfreeze It

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, freeze

So I wrote the following cmd file:

```
:he
time < time.txt
goto he
```

The contents of time.txt are:

```
00:00:00.00
```

My goal here was to freeze my Windows 7 clock to see if it caused a program on my computer to stock updating (it did). However, there is a problem.

I cannot figure out how to close the script. Attempting to kill with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is not working. Clicking the X in the window is not working. I attempted to press <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>delete</kbd> but apparently Windows 7 with a frozen clock said nope and after 5 minutes on a black screen booted me back to my desktop without task manager.

Essentially my computer is bricked by accidental malware. How do I stop this runaway train wreck of an application? Is there some other menu that might respond instead of locking up?

Comment: @JitendraSingh I cannot get to system restore. Start menu won’t open. I’m not sure what that would accomplish though. Care to elaborate while I wait to see if start menu ever opens?

Comment: Ok at this point it is clear the start menu is NOT gonna open. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you just tried restarting the computer?

Comment: @music2myear I have unsaved data I would rather not lose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTRL-ALT-DEL is the closest thing you have to an interrupt on Windows. If that isn't working you are left with one option whether you like it or not: restart.

Comment: Well, it worked. Thanks.